# Proper way to get char from function that returns int?

Tags: c++, c, file

I'm using a file system library and I'm trying to create a readline function.

```
int al_fgetc(ALLEGRO_FILE *f)
```

> Introduced in 5.0.0
>
> Read and return next byte in the given file. Returns EOF on end of file or if an error occurred.

That is the function I'm using from the library. What I want to do is += the resulting char into a std string if it is  != EOF which is -1. I'm just not sure if I need to cast it to get the correct result. Will something like this do it:

```
bool File::readLine( std::string& buff )
{
    if(eof() || !isOpen())
    {
        return false;
    }
    buff = "";
    int c = 0;
    while(c = al_fgetc(m_file) != EOF && c != '\n')
    {
        buff += (char)c;
    }
    return buff.length() > 0;
}
```

I'm going to be reading utf-8 from file so I need to make sure this works correctly.

Thanks

Comment: And by += i assume you mean append to the end of the string?

Comment: Please don't use C-style casts in C++ but `static_cast<char>(c)` operator instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will work, except you need an extra set of parentheses because the `!=` operator has higher precedence than the `=` operator:

```
while((c = al_fgetc(m_file)) != EOF && c != '\n')
    ...
```

The only reason that `fgetc` returns `int` instead of `char` is that there are 257 possible return values: all 256 possible bytes, or `EOF`, which signals that there's no more data left in the file.  It will always return either 0-255 or `EOF`, so it's safe to cast the return value to `char` or `unsigned char` once you've tested it for `EOF`.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the only reason why they return int is because there is no "free" value in a char that could be used for the EOF signaling. Thus, checking that it's not EOF and afterwards casting it back to char is precisely what they expect you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try using feof(m_file) to check that you've hit the end of file rather than checking the character returned by fgetc. This should seperate your read loop from the eof check, so no casting is necessary.